# How to disable column order drag-and-drop in Windows 7/Server 2008?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-server-2008

Explorer in pre-Windows 7/Server 2008 (and maybe Vista) did not have this new drag-and-drop "feature" of re-ordering columns.

I'm finding it increasingly irritating (especially in a RDP session) trying to resize the column width of the first "Name" column whereas in older versions of Explorer, you could easily double-click it to auto-expand the width.  Now, it's so finicky (again, especially in a somewhat slow RDP session) that I can't even get the cursor to change to the "I" to allow me to resize it without mistakenly grabbing the column header and moving it.

Any way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how you can do that but I can suggest an alternative solution to your original problem, which is expanding column width.

To do that, simply right click the column header that you want to expand and select `Size Column to Fit` from the context menu.

[image]

Comment: Didn't even think to right-click.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

[This page helped me](http://connectppe.microsoft.com/WindowsServerFeedback/feedback/details/605778/provide-easier-column-resizing-in-windows-explorer-e-g-allow-setting-of-column-resize-handle-width-in-advanced-appearance) - the resize is slightly to the right of the line rather than over the top of it